# Symbols for symmetric difference

Tags: symbols

I have the problem with a symbol for symmetric difference (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference). In commonly used is

```
\triangle
\ominus
```

But in Polish tradition often is used:

```
\dot{-}
```

and I would like to ask if it is possible to make dot be a little bit down to (close to) line (here where is the red dot).

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've shifted the dot down relative to `\dot{-}`.  You may adjust the value of `.2\LMex` to suit.

EDITED to make it more robust and to achieve a more uniform vertical spacing at the smaller math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}% IF YOU NEED IT FOR SCRIPTSTYLE MATH
\newcommand\symdif{\ThisStyle{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{.2\LMex}{\SavedStyle-}{\SavedStyle\dot{}}{U}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}}}
\begin{document}
\( A \symdif B \)
\(\scriptstyle A \symdif B \)
\(\scriptscriptstyle A \symdif B \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don’t you use a length register for `\dysym`, i.e. `\newlength\dysym \setlength\dysym{-3pt}`?

Comment: @Tobi  See revision with `\scriptstyle`.  If length register were used, the dot-dash spacing would not shrink in the smaller math style.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- well, i've tried out what i was suggesting, and you're correct -- it doesn't work.  i retract (and have removed) my comment.  (but i still feel there's a less complex way; i'll experiment.)

Answer (score 9):

The main problem is that the minus sign has usually the same height as the plus sign. With `\ooalign` one can avoid this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\providecommand{\dotminus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\xdotminus\relax}}
\newcommand{\xdotminus}[2]{%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\vcenter{\hbox{$#1\dot{}$}}$\hidewidth\cr$#1-$\cr}%
}

\begin{document}
$A\dotminus B$
\end{document}
```

I use `\providecommand` because at least one package (`MnSymbol`) defines it; but it's not advisable to load the package, that changes all math symbols.

[image]